# Git stash apply and drop

Tags: git

Is there a git command that both applies the stash and removes it?

This as one command:

```
git stash apply
git stash drop
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You want [`git stash pop`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)!

```
pop [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
       Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on
       top of the current working tree state, i.e., do the inverse
       operation of git stash save. The working directory must match the
       index.
```

Comment: Note that if a conflict occurs as a result of "git stash pop", the stash is not dropped. Once the conflicts have been resolved (and preferably committed) you'll need to drop the stash yourself.

Comment: @Adam But what if I want to `git stash pop` specific stash like `stash@{1}` and still don't wanna do 2 commands `apply` and `drop` for that ?

Answer (score 23):

`git stash pop` will take the first stash in your list (or the one you specify), apply it to your `HEAD`, and delete it from the stash list.

Comment: But what if I want to `git stash pop` specific stash like `stash@{1}` and still don't wanna do 2 commands `apply` and `drop` for that ?

Comment: @VickyDev, [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778460/git-stash-apply-and-drop#comment133128565_14778509), actually the answer already addresses that: you can `pop` the stash you prefer with, say, `git stash pop 1`.